# Get Image File Size in IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get file size from clientside without using activex in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911566/how-to-get-file-size-from-clientside-without-using-activex-in-javascript)

I'm using image upload of maximum size 1 GB in my script and i need to get image file size in javascript so i used the following script,

```
var file = document.getElementById('image').files[0];

if(file.size > 1048576){
    alert('image size is too big to upload');
}
```

This script works fine in all browsers except IE8,9. Suggest me some solution to work in IE.

Comment: i am afraid there is no such way to do it with til now , for IE to be compatible with the issue you have to use server side validation only for image size

Comment: Hussain is correct. Other options in IE 8 and 9 are SilverLight and Flash. A painful situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = sYourFilePath;
var iSize = img.fileSize;
```

Read more

[How to get file size from clientside without using activex in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911566/how-to-get-file-size-from-clientside-without-using-activex-in-javascript)

https://gist.github.com/3347948

Answer (score 0):

Can't seem to find a link for reference, but ie8 and ie8 don't support the html5 file api, meaning you can't get the file size from there. An alternative is to do this processing on the server side and fail fast if the size goes over the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example from [Here](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/check-for-file-size-with-javascript-before-uploading.html)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getSize()
{
    var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
    var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
    var size = thefile.size;
    alert(size + " bytes");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="upload">
<input type="file" name="file">
<input type="button" value="Size?" onClick="getSize();">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

But you need to allow [ActiveX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751968%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE security settings.

Answer (score 0):

**Requirement**
To calculate file/image size on client side the browser should support HTML5 File API

**Reason/Detail**
You can not get Image/File size in any IE version upto IE 9.0, even HTML File API is partial supported in IE 10.0 [Check this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)

**Research**

Here is debug information IE vs Chrome using following code

```
var file = document.getElementById('image').files[0];
console.log(file);
```

**Chrome**
Chrome
webkitRelativePath: "", 
lastModifiedDate: Wed Feb 08 2012 12:57:57 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time), 
name: "1.jpg", 
type: "image/jpeg", 
size: 715285…
}

**IE 9.0**
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property '0': object is null or undefined